# Ruby on Rails 4 - How to get a has_many association for a group of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following setup in my database. We have users. Each user has many entries. Users also belong to organizations, through a table called organization_users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :entries
     has_many :organization_users
     has_many :organizations, :through => :organization_users
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :organization_users
     has_many :users, :through => :organization_users
end

class OrganizationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :organization
end
```

Here's my question: for a given organization, I want to get a list of all the entries for the users in that organization. Is there a nice compact way to accomplish this? I know I can iterate over all users in the organization and get the entries, but I'm not sure if there is a nice rails-y way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following assuming you have a foreign key called `organization_id` in `organization_users` table as per your Model

```
Entry.joins(:user => :organization_users).where("organization_users.organization_id = ?", org_id)
```

Where `org_id` is the `id` of the given organization. This will give you all entries of all users in an organization

Comment: hey thanks but this query doesn't provide a list of entries for all the users in an org

Comment: @user402516 updated the answer with the list of entries for all users in an org.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
my_org = Organization.find(id)
my_org.users.eager_load(:entries)
```

First you get the organization you want to query. Then via :through association you can directly retrieve all the users for that organization. And last using eager_load, in one query you get all the entries. The result will be an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: This won't work because once you retrieve all the users via `my_org.users`, rails returns a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` object, not an instance of `ActiveRecord`. Therefore, you can't call `entries` on a `CollectionProxy`. Your method can only work if you retrieve a single user like so: `my_org.users.first.entries`

Comment: this looks promising, but when I run your statements above, I get back ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation that is of the users and not their entries. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you just want entries ? In this AssociationRelation you have all users AND their entries. You must loop on each user and then you can directly access their entries without querying your database. All in one.